# Tell Linux to not swap until a certain amount of RAM

Tags: linux, limit, swap

I'm facing a very ironic situation: The swap that is supposed to help me slows down everything because it starts to swap when 3GB of RAM are used, much less before the 4GB my computer has.

Is it possible to tell Debian to not swap until I reach x amount of RAM ?

Edit: Problem solved.

That stupid swap still kicks in even with swappiness = 0.
So I completely disabled it with swapoff -a and enable it again when I need it with swapon -a

Comment: You have 4GB of RAM, so you set up 2GB of swap space, not more, right?

Comment: I put like 16GB of swap, since I am planning to upgrade my computer soon.

Comment: My bet is that you are misunderstanding what is happening. Can you paste stats showing significant swapping while only 75% of your RAM is used? I'll bet you can't.

Comment: @user, well, that's your problem. Your swap space is out-weighting your RAM 4 to 1. Of course it will get used before your RAM is full.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Generally speaking, how much swap you have has no effect so long as you have enough for your workload. More has little to no effect.

Comment: @David, it's been a long time since I had to tinker with swap space on Linux, but back when I started every piece of documentation under the sun (ha!) recommended to set swap to half the RAM on the system at most. Doing otherwise was asking for trouble. Could you provide a reference that says the size of the swap space relative to RAM is not a problem anymore?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It starts to swap at 3GB of RAM, but the little (128MB) that is swapped is enough to slow down the entire system.

Comment: @user3755746 You've misdiagnosed the problem. Your OS is not dumb. It's swapped the tiny bit of memory that has never been accessed and likely never will be accessed. That's having no effect on performance.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Is there any way to change the amount of RAM when swap should kicks in ?
I will also have a use of this swap, since I'm using a lot of ram and also hibernating inbetween.
"Could you provide a reference that says the size of the swap space relative to RAM is not a problem anymore?": Je ne comprends pas :/

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I can't imagine any sane reason for such a recommendation. The classic recommendation was two to three times the amount of memory, and that was based on avoiding the risk of (lack of) overcommit problems. I think you are drawing conclusions based on very atypical experiences you had.

Comment: @user, to my knowledge, no, but don't take my word for it, there are *lots* of options you can pass to the kernel and I don't know all of them. (My request for references was aimed at David, not you :)

Comment: @David, I dug a little and it appears you're right. Recommendations apparently go from "twice the RAM" when RAM is low (~256M), "same as RAM" when it is average, and several different and contradicting values when the available amount of RAM is large.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi For the past few years, we've been telling people to just assign more than you could possibly need so you don't have to worry about it. That worked great in the days of 500GB and larger hard drives. But now that people have SSDs, it's becoming an issue again.

Answer (score 2):

You have a very common misconception that swapping makes your system slow. If that was true, nobody would swap. Your operating system is smart enough to only swap where that provides a benefit.

The tiny amount of swapping you're seeing is memory that likely has never been accessed and, believe it or not, the data swapped is probably still in RAM as well. Opportunistic swapping just permits the OS to discard the data without having to write it out, which may provide a benefit if there's a memory shortage later.

Your performance problems are likely unrelated to swap. This is a common misdiagnosis.

*Needing* to swap may make a system slow, but having the option to swap if it benefits you doesn't.

Comment: To me, swapping should be done only if I don't have enough RAM (a least start from 3.75 GB) or if I want to hibernate.
The problem kicks in when my system uses 250MB, my browser 600MB and 1664MB allocated RAM for a VM and that I am using my browser which uses around 600MB: The swap slows everything because it swaps parts of the system and the browser.

Comment: @user3755746 Essentially, you're saying that you know more about how an OS should manage memory to provide good performance than the folks who wrote your operating system's memory manager. I find that unlikely in the extreme. (And you're wrong. The worst time to swap is when circumstances force you to do a lot of I/O, because that's when doing I/O hurts performance the most. The best time to write to swap is when you're not doing anything else.)

Comment: You wouldn't tell me that if you meet the same problem as I do, nothing more.

Comment: If I encountered the same problem you did, I'd diagnose it and, with luck, figure out the cause. I'm just saying that you have misdiagnosed the cause due to having some common misconceptions about what swap does and how modern operating systems use it. I don't doubt that you have a real problem and would be happy to help you diagnose it if you described it in detail.

Answer (score 0):

As David said, what you want is not possible.
But there is a possibility to configure how much linux tends to swap.
It is the kernel parameter "vm.swappiness". 
Default value is 60. As an example, when you set it to extreme low value zero, the kernel will only swap to avoid an out of memory.

Comment: Which is, of course, the *worst* time to swap since that's when you most need I/O bandwidth.

Comment: And this is what's happening in my case ^^"
Is it only possible to change that via a kernel parameter ?